# Route from aspx code behind to MCV controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a hybrid aspx/mvc application and want to route from the aspx code behind to an mvc controller. I am missing something... To keep this simple: I have a button in my aspx page:

```
<asp:Button ID="Attendees" runat="server" OnClick="Attendees_Click"/>
```

to my code behind:

```
protected void Attendees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //How can this be redirected this to my Attendee/Index Controller?
     //Url.Redirect("Index","Attendee");//This does not work?
     Response.Redirect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually by mentioning the path of controller name and action name should work:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Attendee/Index");
```

However if the above way doesn't work, the best way is using [`UrlHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) instance to create target URL (with [`UrlHelper.Action()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_UrlHelper_Action_System_String_System_String_) overload) and redirect afterwards:

```
var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
Response.Redirect(url.Action("Index", "Attendee"));
```